# $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x} =0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I wanted to prove $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x} =0$ by the squeeze theorem.

I know $$e^x =1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\dots$$ by Taylor expansion, so
$e^x \ge 1+x$ and thus $x \ge \ln(1+x)$ and finally, $x \ge \ln(x)$.

I also know $\ln x \ge 0$ for $x\geq 1$.

So I tried to apply the squeeze theorem $0 \le \ln x \le x$, and then dividing throughout by $x$ I get $0 \le \frac{\ln x}{x} \le 1$ and then if I apply limit $x \to \infty$, but I'm unable to apply the squeeze theorem here.

Can anybody help me understand what is it that I'm doing wrong?
I do not want to use L'Hospital's theorem.

Comment: The limit is not 1, it is zero.

Comment: $$x=e^{\ln x}\geq\frac{(\ln x)^2}2$$ by the Taylor series, for $x>1.$

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you cant apply L'Hospital's rule? Its by far the fastest way to obtain the limit...

Comment: Also, could it be possible to consider... $\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2} \leq \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \leq \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$, for $x \ge 1$

Comment: I have not done derivatives yet...so no L'Hospital's for me....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\ln x=2 \ln x^{\frac 12}\le2\sqrt x$ (using the inequality $y\ge \ln y$ for $y\gt 0$ that you obtained.)

So it follows that: for all $x\gt 0$ $$|\frac{\ln x}x|\le2 \frac{\sqrt x}x$$

It follows by squeeze theorem that $\lim_{x\to \infty}|\frac{\ln x}x|=0.$  Now note that $-|\frac{\ln x}x|\le \frac{\ln x}x\le|\frac{\ln x}x|$ and hence the result follows by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to show: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln x}{x} = 0$. This is immediate since $0 < \dfrac{\ln x}{x} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}, x > 10$.

Comment: how did you get $0 < \dfrac{\ln x}{x} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: I guess using that $\ln(x)<x$ for $x>10$

Comment: $$
\frac{d}{{dx}}(\sqrt x  - \ln x) = \frac{1}{{2\sqrt x }}\left( {1 - \frac{2}{{\sqrt x }}} \right) > 0
$$ for $x>4$. Thus $\sqrt x  - \ln x$ is increasing for $x>4$. Also, $\sqrt 10 -\ln 10 >0$. Hence, the inequality follows.

Comment: @Orpheus . If $x>1$ then $\ln x=2\ln\sqrt x<2\sqrt x$ because $\ln x>0\implies \sqrt x=\exp (\ln\sqrt x)>\ln \sqrt x$ because if $0<y=\ln \sqrt x$ then $\sqrt x=e^y=1+y+y^2/2!+...>y.$

Answer (score 2):

Extending the approximation

$$e^x\ge 1+x$$

into

$$e^x\ge 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}>\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}$$

and

$$e^x\ge 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}>\frac{(x+1)^3}{6}$$

allows

$$e^x> \frac{(x+1)^n}{n!}$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So,

$$x\ge n\ln(1+x)-\ln n!\ge n\ln x - \ln n!$$

So

$$\frac{x}{n}+\frac{\ln n!}{n}\ge \ln x$$

$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\ln n!}{nx}\ge \frac{\ln x}{x}$$

As we can make both terms on the LHS arbitrarily small, we are done.

Comment: what do you mean by saying both terms in LHS can be made small?

Comment: @Orpheus; $n$ can be as large as we want, so $1/n\to0$, and for $x>>\ln n!$, $\frac{\ln n!}{x}\to0$ also. So the LHS tends to $0$, and so the squeeze theorem gives the limit as $0$.

Comment: I liked your thinking...very intuitive...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with the integral definition.

If $x > 1$ then

$\ln(x)
=\int_1^x \dfrac{dt}{t}
$
so,
for any $c > 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+x)
&=\int_1^{1+x} \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&=\int_0^{x} \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&<\int_0^{x} \dfrac{dt}{(1+t)^{1-c}}
\qquad\text{(since } (1+t)^{1-c} < 1+c\\
&=\int_0^{x} (1+t)^{c-1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{(1+t)^c}{c}\big|_0^x\\
&=\dfrac{(1+x)^c-1}{c}\\
&<\dfrac{(1+x)^c}{c}\\
\text{Therefore}\\
\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{(1+x)^{2c}}
&<\dfrac1{c(1+x)^c}\\
\end{array}
$

or, for $x > 1$
and any $c > 0$,
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^{2c}}
\lt\dfrac1{cx^c}
$.

For example,
if $c = \frac12$,
this gives
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}
\lt\dfrac{2}{x^{1/2}}
$.

Replacing $c$
by $c/2$,
this gives
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^{c}}
\lt\dfrac{2}{cx^{c/2}}
$
which shows that
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^{c}}
\to 0$
as $x \to \infty$
for any $c > 0$.